# Price want to show including and excluding tax in catalogue and also in shopping cart

Tags: magento2.3, tax-calculation

I tried many things to display the price of a product including and excluding tax but no result as i wish.
I made a rule for 21 percent. Also tried different things in configuration but no result.
Is this a bug?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display both prices on catalog page you have to change "Display Product Prices In Catalog" field in `Stores->Configuration->Sales->Tax->Price Display Settings`.
Change to `Excluding and including tax`. After this please run `php bin/magento c:c` and `php bin/magento c:f`

**EDIT:**
under `Price Display Settings` you have `Shopping cart display settings`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks Sebastian,
2 things.

1. Excluding and including Tax will not be shown at product page. Only the price, not excluding or including. I changed it of course in display settings. What to do about this?
   [![enter image description here][1]][1]
2. In shopping cart it is good now but only uses some english language while most is allready in dutch. How can i change this?

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[![enter image description here][4]][4]

[image]

[image]

Comment: 1. It should show both prices. All settings are in ```Stores->Configuration->Sales->Tax``` please check all information you have there.
2. Check in Stores->Configuration->Genereal->General if you have set Netherlands as default country.

Comment: I will add some pictures. Netherland is default.

Comment: How can i show a printscreen to your answer?

Comment: edit your answer

Comment: Thanks, i added 2 pictures. In my opinion it is well adjusted but no....

Comment: Taxes are a little bit complicated. It looks like it should works. You have to try different configuration. Try to set everywhere including and excluding and see what happen. After changes run c:c and c:f

Comment: It does not matter what i do. In the product page it only shows price (not included or excluded)

Comment: I added a new picture, now it is shown excl. BTW but in configuration i marked in and excluding BTW. So it is still not the same, unbelievable. It has to be a bug?

Comment: do you use custom theme ? or you work on magento luma?

Comment: magento luma i guess?

Comment: In tax rule additional settings create your class for product. and then in this specify product in admin panel (catalog->products->your product) you have tax class. choose yours. You need to set tax class for product.

Comment: I also did that. I show you printscreens. Maybe you see something wrong?

Comment: I find the solution finally myself. When the changes you make in backend will not be executed in frontend, than you can best do a reindex too. So not only refresh your cache! It was not enough in this case.

Comment: How can i close this question as solved?

Comment: mark answer as solved, it will be closed.

Comment: I dont see where the solve button is?

Comment: next to answer, where you have arrow up -> points -> arrow down -> grey tick. If you click it it will become green

Comment: Check my updated answer

Comment: Thanks Sebastian